# Named docker volumes are not visible across the swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a swarm with a manager-worker (node A) and a worker (node B)

I have created named mounted volumes in both A and B like this:

```
node-A> docker volume create --opt type=none --opt device=/minio-1.media-server/storage/ --opt o=bind ssd-1-vol
```

```
node-B> docker volume create --opt type=none --opt device=/minio-2.media-server/storage/ --opt o=bind ssd-2-vol
```

However I noticed something odd when I do `docker volume ls`: `ssd-1-vol` is not visible from `node-B`, and `ssd-2-vol` is not visible from `node-A`. This means that I can't reference `ssd-2-vol` as part of a docker compose or docker stack deployment, correct?

Both nodes are running `19.03.5`

Answer (score 1):

Local volumes are not shared in the swarm, they can be only (bind)mounted on the same node they have been created. You need to use a network enabled storage driver for sharing across the cluster.

Comment: well, the point precisely was to deploy a storage server (as Min.IO) mounting local volumes, and I know for a fact that docker services can be created with local binds, it should still be visible so that a services on node B (worker) can be deployed from A using node-B only resources, but if node A cannot see the volumes on B, then it is much pretty useless for deploying on non-manager nodes